# how to keep session alive untill user does not click on logout button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, session, web-config

i am creating asp.net website in this website i have managed sessions in various modules
and i also change the web.config settings but the problems is that my session is expired automatically after hosting my website. Its working fine on my local host but after hosting it session expired after some minutes.
i want to keep session alive for long time or until user does not click on logout button

in my application i just want to calculate user login and logout time no matter user is using my application or not
he just login when he come and logout at the time of leaving
i just want some sample code that can send request to server in background and can keep session alive for all my pages
(i have 8 master pages in my application)

Comment: simply ping the server (load a url via ajax) from js every few mins to extend the session.

Comment: @dandavis i have did same but still not extend session.

Answer (score 0):

On page_load() event, store your session in a local variable.
like :

```
 string sid = "";
sid = Sesion["id"];
```

Comment: i have lots of pages its looking very lengthy i want simple code that can keep all session alive or any code for master pages

Comment: Look here! [HERE](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Keep-Session-Alive.aspx) there are many ways to do it.